# Parsing a line with three number groups using regexp

Tags: regex, scala

I want to parse git shortstat lines. E.g.

```
val in  = """ 6 files changed, 55 insertions(+), 1 deletions(-)"""
val out = (6, 55, 1)
```

How do I get `out` from `in`? I tried regexp, but probably got them wrong:

```
import util.Try

val Ex = """ (\d+) files changed, (\d+) insertions\(+\), (\d+) deletions\(-\)""".r

def parse(line: String): Option[(Int, Int, Int)] = line match {
  case Ex(a, b, c) => (for {
      ai <- Try(a.toInt)
      bi <- Try(b.toInt)
      ci <- Try(c.toInt)
    }
    yield (ai, bi, ci)).toOption

  case _ => None
}
```

But something is wrong: `parse(in) == None`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to escape the `+`:

```
//                                                  !!
val Ex = """ (\d+) files changed, (\d+) insertions\(\+\), (\d+) deletions\(-\)""".r
```

Comment: I don't see why you would need to escape a `-`